# Embedded clause or not?

Tags: grammar

He told me that when he was in London he met nice people.

What is the grammatical function of "when he was in London"? Is it embedded subordinate clause ? 
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's an adverb phrase, which amplifies the adverb *when* in that sentence.

You can look at [some examples of other adverb phrases](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/adverb-phrase-examples.html) to get a feel for them.